# How can I emulate input event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("input", function(){
  console.log("input event fired.");
})

$("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
  var event = new Event('input');
 $("input[type=text]").dispatchEvent(event);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="write .." />
<input type="button" value="emulate input event" />
```

As you can see, when you write something into the input, `input` event works as well. How can I emulate that event when you click on the button?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

If you want to use dispachtEvent, you need the DOM element.

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("input", function(){
  console.log("input event fired.");
})

$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  // EITHER
  $("input[type=text]").trigger("input");
  // OR
  var event = new Event('input');
  $("input[type=text]")[0].dispatchEvent(event); // DOM 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="write .." />
<input type="button" value="emulate input event" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("input", function(){
  console.log("input event fired.");
})

$("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
 $("input[type=text]").trigger("input");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="write .." />
<input type="button" value="emulate input event" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** method to fire the event by name like :

```
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
    $("input[type=text]").trigger("input");
})
```

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("input", function() {
  console.log("input event fired.");
})

$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $("input[type=text]").trigger("input");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="write .." />
<input type="button" value="emulate input event" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can just call the event type on the element.

To invoke a click event on an element do:

```
$("foo").click();
```

For an input field, the best option is usually to

```
$("foo").change();
```